# what is the solution of $ \int e^{-3} . x^{-3} dx $?

Tags: integration

What is the integration of $ \int e^{-3} . x^{-3} dx $ and how to derive it?

Comment: Is it $\int e^{-3} \cdot x^{-3} dx$

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: what do you mean by $e^{-3}$? I think it should be $e^{-3x}$? which else is very simple! since $e^{-3}$ is constant and will come out of integration and the integration of the rest is $-\frac{1}{2} x^{-2}$. So the whole answer is $- \frac{e^{-3} x^{-2} }{2}.$

Comment: indeed i needed $e^{-3x}$ later. and i though they could be solved in the same way! @farrokh

Answer (score 2):

One may recall that,
$$
(x^{\alpha+1})'=(\alpha+1)\:x^{\alpha}, \quad \alpha \in \mathbb{R},
$$ giving, with $\alpha=-3$,
$$
(x^{-2})'=-2\cdot x^{-3}.
$$ Observe that $e^{-3}$ is just a constant number.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: yes i can! one more help please. what if e^-3 was replaced by e^-x?

Comment: @RockyJohnson Then it will be different: some integrations by parts would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$I=\int e^{-3} \cdot x^{ -3}dx$$

Since $e^-3$ is a constant and $\int  x^{ n}dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} +c$,

$$I=e^{-3}\int   x^{ -3}dx$$.

$$I=e^{-3}\cdot \frac{x^{-3+1}}{-3+1} + c$$.

$$I=e^{-3}\cdot \frac{x^{-2}}{-2} + c$$.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple.

$$\int e^{-3} \cdot x^{ -3}dx=e^{-3} \int x^{ -3}dx=e^{-3} \frac{x^{-2}}{-2}+c=\frac{-1}{2e^3}x^{-2}+c$$

I think you might need the answer for $$\int e^{-3x} \cdot x^{ -3}dx$$ which needs a different technique to be solved.